# Removing space after hiding labels with Autolayout

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have three UILabel's on top of each other, but I would like to hide the second label and move the third label higher to take the same place as the original second label. Right now, my code hides the second label and I have made the constraint to 0 but the autolayout constraints are staying the same so there is still a large space between the first and third label.

I have seen other questions addressing UIViews, but none about UILabels and they don't discuss how to remove the original autolayout constraints

```
secondLabel.isHidden = true
secondLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 0
```

Comment: Try UIStackView

Comment: Sorry, should've been more clear. The third label has an ImageView next to it so is it possible to stackview all three labels AND the imageview?

Comment: Firstly a UILabel is a subclass of UIView so anything about layout applies to them equally (not text alignment though obviously).  Secondly if the third label has a UIImageView next to it and you want them to stay together put them in their own UIView (or UIStackView) so they are treated as a single item in the UIStackView.  Thirdly if you put the labels in a UIStackView you just need to hide them not adjust any constraints.

Comment: It would be nice to have a *lot* more than you've given us. Based on your words.... *"I have three UILabel's on top of each other...hide the second label and move the third label higher to take the same place as the original second..."* the obvious answer should be (1) don't mess with constraints, (2) don't use `isHidden`, but *instead* (3) in the superview, use `bring(toFront:)` on the subview you want in front. If this doesn't work, then *please* add more detail to your question!

Answer (score 1):

You can put three of your labels into stack view and then using their outlets you can hide it. i.e `lbl1.isHidden = true` Or if you do not want to use stack view you can use following link https://github.com/snoozelag/GoneVisible it is equivalent to android gone method which you can claim space to your labels. First thing that you will do is `lbl1.isHidden = true`  then `lbl1.gone()`